# JS - hide divs after certain count in pure JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a page where the user can enter as many divs with a specific class they want (filterDiv). I want to have a Load More button display if the number if items is more than nine.

Problem is I am trying to access the divs with class filterDiv after the ninth iteration and add a hide class.

Here is my code:

```
const htCount = document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv').length;

if (htCount > 9){
  document.querySelector('#loadMore').classList.add('show'); // load more button shows

};
```

How would I add a code to hide divs 10,11,12 etc. until the Load More button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a document with divs that look like this:

```
<div class=“myDiv”> content </div>
```

You can first get all the divs:

```
var myDivs = document.getEmementsByClassName(“myDiv”);
```

Then loop through them and hide some of them by specifying their style attribute like this:

```
for(var i = 9; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
    myDivs[i].style.display = “none”
}
```

So we are looping through indexes from 9 till the end of array and making them invisible.
The direct style property of item has higher priority than css of class, so elements will hide and you can specify all the properties of visible elements in css.

Then when a button is clicked, you can do the same loop and just change to `.style.display = “block”`

```
for(var i = 9; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
    myDivs[i].style.display = “block”
}
```